# iCalendar (.ics) attachment can't be added in Gmail app to Apple Calendar

Tags: mail.app, calendar, gmail, ical, google-calendar

`.ics` attached can be viewed in Gmail app, but there are no button to add it to Apple Calendar.

Gmail image:

[image]

In Mail app the window looks same but has buttons to add the event:

[image]

Also there is no option to share the attachment into the Calendar directly.
I see that Gmail app parsed the event info, but even with Google Calendar installed I can not do anything with it. I have these options in Gmail app on Android.

Why is that and is there another easy option to import this event without Apple Mail?
It's Google who did not code this feature or Apple's restriction?

Edit: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251135443 no answer to "why".

Comment: Download the ics attachment and open with Calendar.app and sync your google calendar account with Calendar.app. Possibly you can import/drag the file onto google calendar too.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @codecowboy AFAIK no

Answer (score 0):

> You can sync Google Calendar with the Calendar app that comes on your
> iPhone or iPad.
>
> 1. On your iPhone or iPad, open your device settings.
> 2. Scroll and tap **Calendar..**
> 3. Tap **Accounts** and then **Add account** and then **Google**.
> 4. Enter your email address and then **Next**.
> 5. Enter your password. If you don't have the latest operating system and you use 2-Step Verification, enter an app password instead of your
>    regular password.
> 6. Tap **Next**.
> 7. Emails, contacts, and calendar events will now sync directly with your Google Account. To sync only your calendar, turn off the other
>    services.
> 8. Open the Calendar app on your iPhone to find your Google Calendar events.
>
> To sync with an existing account, tap the account and turn on
> Calendars.

Source: [Google Calendar Help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS)

Comment: Welcome to [apple.se]! Please have a look at the [attribution guidelines](/help/referencing) which apply across the network.

Answer (score -1):

[This app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/to-calendar-import-ics-files/id1627929869) should be the one to solve this problem

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/323385)

Comment: What is the name of the app?!